# Undefined characters while reading the file content without new line at the end of file

Tags: c++, parsing, ifstream, getline, istringstream

File (settings.txt) to parse:

```
FULLSCREEN=On
V_SYNC=On [no "\n" at the end of file]
```

In case with no ENTER "\n" output is:

```
MapKey= FULLSCREEN      MapValue= On
MapKey= V_SYNC  MapValue= Onřřřř
```

With ENTER "\n" at the end of file output is correct (without "řřřř"):

```
MapKey= FULLSCREEN      MapValue= On
MapKey= V_SYNC  MapValue= On
```

How to change the program to work without adding new line at the end of file? Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdint>
#include<memory>


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> container;
    std::ifstream containerFile("settings.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
    containerFile.seekg(0, containerFile.end);
    std::uint64_t fileSize = containerFile.tellg();
    containerFile.seekg(0);
    std::unique_ptr<char> fileBuffer(new char[fileSize]);
    containerFile.read(fileBuffer.get(), fileSize);

    std::istringstream fileContent(fileBuffer.get());
    std::string fileLine;
    while (std::getline(fileContent, fileLine))
    {
        std::istringstream bufferLine(fileLine);
        std::string option;
        if (std::getline(bufferLine, option, '='))
        {
            std::string value;
            if (std::getline(bufferLine, value))
            {
                container.emplace_back(make_pair(option, value));
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto &element : container)
    {
        std::cout << "MapKey= " << element.first << "   MapValue= " << element.second << std::endl;
    }
    containerFile.close();
}
```

Comment: `std::istringstream fileContent(fileBuffer.get());` - an improperly null-terminated char buffer is converted to a std::string.  There are many ways to fix this, like explicitly construct the string with a length: `std::istringstream fileContent(std::string(fileBuffer.get(), fileSize));`

Comment: And if this is a Windows system, and if this is a standard text file, reading with `std::ifstream::binary` will keep the extra carriage returns before each linefeed character :  (`"\r\n"`), which might also cause parsing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code in this way:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> container;
std::ifstream containerFile("settings.txt");
containerFile.seekg(0, containerFile.end );
std::uint64_t fileSize = containerFile.tellg();
containerFile.seekg(0);

/* Changed code. Begin*/
containerFile >> std::noskipws;
std::vector<char> buffer;
buffer.reserve(fileSize);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(containerFile), std::istream_iterator<char>(), std::back_inserter(buffer));
buffer.push_back('\0');
std::istringstream fileContent(&buffer.front());
/* Changed code. End*/

std::string fileLine;
while (std::getline(fileContent, fileLine))
{
    std::istringstream bufferLine(fileLine);
    std::string option;
    if (std::getline(bufferLine, option, '='))
    {
        std::string value;
        if (std::getline(bufferLine, value))
        {
            container.emplace_back(make_pair(option, value));
        }
    }
}
for (auto &element : container)
{
    std::cout << "MapKey= " << element.first << "   MapValue= " << element.second << std::endl;
}
containerFile.close();
```

First of all you have to use the next flag: `containerFile >> std::noskipws;` 
It allows you to use whitespaces. Tab spaces, carriage returns and blank spaces are all considered whitespaces [according to documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/).

Correct string representation requires [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) in the end, so the next line `buffer.push_back('\0');` adds '\0' to the end of the buffer.

Comment: I don't see why '\0' needs adding at all. If this was a ASCIIZ C-string, yes. But for a C++ string it is not required.